Filtering a pandas series consisting of lists and NaN values if the elements contain a string
Let's consider this dataframe:
temp = pd.DataFrame({'x': [['ab', 'bc'], ['hg'], np.nan]})
temp

    x
0   [ab, bc]
1   [hg]
2   NaN

I'd like to create a new column called dummy that takes the value of 1 if a row contains letter 'a' in any of its elements, value of 0 if it does not, and value of NaN if it's NaN.
Expected outcome:
    x         dummy
0   [ab, bc]   1
1   [hg]       0
2   NaN        NaN

Sounds simple but I'm stuck. What I've tried:
1)
temp['dummy'] = np.where(temp.x.str.contains('a', case = False, na = False), 1, 0)

will assign all 0s because it compares the whole list to 'a'
2)
temp['dummy'] = np.where(temp.x.astype(str).str.contains('a', case = False, na = False), 1, 0)

atype(str) will take care of the above issue by flattening the a list as a string but now np.NaN is 'nan'  and na = False does not work on it.
3)
temp['dummy'] = np.where(all([temp.x.astype(str).str.contains('a', case = False, na = False) , temp.x.astype(str) != 'nan']), 1, 0)

I think my second condition should take care of the above issue but now I get error : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
4)
temp['dummy'] = [1 if all(['a' in y , y != np.nan]) else 0 for y in temp.x ]

Error: TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
5)
The only thing that will work is:
temp['dummy'] = np.nan # placeholder
temp['dummy'][temp.x.notnull()] = np.where(temp[temp.x.notnull()].x.astype(str).str.contains('a', case = False, na = False), 1, 0)
temp

But it's two lines and ugly.

Since pandas is not designed to work with nested components, use a list comprehension:
from collections.abc import Iterable

temp['dummy'] = [int(any('a' in item for item in x))
                 if isinstance(x, Iterable)
                 else x for x in temp['x']]

Variant (which might not necessarily be faster):
m = temp['x'].notna()

temp.loc[m, 'dummy'] = [int(any('a' in item for item in x))
                        for x in temp.loc[m, 'x']]

Or a pure pandas approach with explode, str.contains and aggregation with groupby.any:
temp['dummy'] = (temp['x'].explode()
                 .dropna()
                 .str.contains('a')
                 .groupby(level=0).any()
                 .astype(float)
                )

Output:
          x  dummy
0  [ab, bc]    1.0
1      [hg]    0.0
2       NaN    NaN

timings
with random items among [['ab', 'bc'], ['hg'], np.nan]:

with random items with list of 100 items and NaNs:

In this case the pure pandas approach is slower as it does not benefit from short-circuiting like any.

Thank you. I liked the middle approach the most. I was not aware you can create a new dataframe column while using loc at the same time as in temp.loc[m, 'dummy'] (I thought a column needs to exist first before you can index it)
